# Missing character: there is no 'x' in font nullfont

Tags: fonts, math-mode, formatting

I want to generate an image from a Tex file. I use a template and then programmatically insert LaTeX inside it. For example, if I want to create an image for `x^2 + \phi`, this would be the resulting template file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{minimal}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\pagestyle{empty}
\parindent=0pt
\setbox0=\hbox{
x^2 + \phi
}
\textheight=\ht0
\textwidth=\wd0
\oddsidemargin=-1cm
\topmargin=-1.5cm
\advance\textheight by 1cm
\advance\textwidth by 1cm
\begin{document}
\vbox{\vss\hbox{\hss\copy0\hss}\vss}
\end{document}
```

I don't really know LaTeX, because I've only used it on Math.SE for equations. I've taken this template somewhere and if it can be made better I'm open for suggestions.

However, the problem is that this does not compile! Running `latex source.tex` produces

```
Missing character: There is no x in font nullfont!

! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.10 x^
       2 + \phi
```

My understanding is that some packages are setting the `nullfont` mode, so I cannot input the equation correctly.

Comment: Never use the `minimal` class and never set boxes before `\begin{document}`. The reason for the error message is that `^` is legal only in math mode.

Comment: @egreg Why not use the minimal class? I find it quite handy, especially for TikZ pictures.

Comment: @BenediktBauer The `minimal` class was not designed to be used for anything: it's there as it does the minimum necessary to allow LaTeX to process a `\begin{document}` line. Various core/expected definitions are not made by `minimal` as a result. It was set up for testing in the early 1990s in a very different computing situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't understand the need for the `\setbox`, `\vbox`, and `\hbox` instructions. If all you want to do is to create an image file containing a certain math expression, in a font size of 12pt, you could achieve this objective by writing

```
\documentclass[12pt,preview,border=1pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
$ x^2 + \phi $
\end{document}
```

More elaborate contents than `$ x^2 + \phi $` can be created nearly as easily. E.g., to render the preceding content in displaymath mode and an equation number, you'd write

```
\documentclass[12pt,preview,border=1pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
x^2 + \phi
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I add `\begin{equation}` can I get rid of the dollar signs?

Comment: @rubik - The short answer to your follow-up question is,"yes". I've edited my answer to flesh out this short answer a bit. :-)

Comment: Thanks! Now it's clearer! I'm also considering the double dollars sign.

Comment: @rubik - For LaTeX documents, use of `$$` is deprecated. For more information, see the posting [Why is \\[ ... \\] preferable to $$ ... $$?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5001) For unnumbered displaystyle equations, do use `\[ ... \]`.

Comment: Damn, I had just got used to `$$`... Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1):

use

```
\setbox0=\hbox{%
  $x^2 + \phi$%
}
```

or:

```
\documentclass[12pt,preview,border=1pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\[ x^2 + \phi \]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please a little more detail, like, why this works, and what was the original problem. That will make it look  like an answer, and not a comment.